# Need a good files creation tool

Tags: file, filesystems

I want to create a test setup which should have a 4tb of High density filesystem.
I've tried some tools(wst) but they are crashing after sometime. After struggling for two days im able to fill not even 20% of disk space. I need this tool on windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's a "High density filesystem".

Comment: millions of small files(say 2k to 10k size)

Comment: Does it matter what the contents of the files are?  I.e. can they be full of zero's or do you need random data in them?

Comment: content doesn't matter...can be anything...all i care is size of files(say 2KB to 10KB size)...

Comment: It takes time to do stuff with 4 TB.  What's wrong with Perl - or Python if your of a more modern persuasion?

Comment: I found a 15,000 rpm, 450 GB disk from sun - brochure dated August 2008.  It advertises a maximum sequential read rate of 160 MB/s.  Assuming that the write rate is the same, that's 6 seconds per GB, or about 2 hours per TB, or 8 hours solid writing to fill 4 TB.  However, that ignores the fact that you are creating thousands of tiny files.  Each such file requires data entered into the directory structure - typically several times for safety.  That means you are no longer doing sequential writing; you are hopping around the disk, and trashing the performance.

Comment: For random 2KB reads, it gives a maximum rate of 350 IOPs per second; that's 700 KB/s (radically slower than 160 MB/s). Do the math; it takes time...  For the record: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-2723-10

Comment: ... which is why you want a smart tool. Would be a bitch to write for NTFS, but for Ext2 it's certainly possible. The tool would programatically generate the filesystem clusters and write them out sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Disk Tools](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-file-generator/index.html). I used it once for stress testing a hard disk which presumably had bad sectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. create a small file in a directory,
2. copy-paste the directory itself,
3. put the duplicate directory into the original one,

and repeat steps 2 and 3 until you reach your need (about thirty times, depending on the size of the initial file).

Comment: Windows can't copy a directory anymore if there are millions of files in it (at least not with Copy&paste). If you don't run out of memory, you'll run out of patience first (since windows will load all the file names into RAM before starting the paste).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is simply to create many many files, you can use this batch script that copies a given file for as many times as possible. There is no stop condition, but I suppose the counter variable will overflow after about 2^31.

Use the script like `extreme_copy my_test_file.txt` where the test file can have any size you want.

This is the script:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%1"=="" GOTO END
IF NOT EXIST "%1" GOTO END

REM copy loop
SET FILE_NUMBER=1

:COPY

copy "%1" "%~dpn1_%FILE_NUMBER%%~x1" > nul

REM show some progress
SET /A SHOW_ITERATIONS="%FILE_NUMBER% %% 1000"
IF /I %SHOW_ITERATIONS%==0 ECHO %FILE_NUMBER% files created...

SET /A FILE_NUMBER=%FILE_NUMBER% + 1

GOTO COPY

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a C# console app do create random files, with random content from 2kb to 10kb.
Compile it ( this is .net 2, but im sure it will compile with any .NET version )
Run like this: 
YourExe d:
YourExe d:\temp2

Semi disclaimer, if you run the app long enough it might get  a [stackoverflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), just start it again if that happens. File names are random, so it will not create any issues

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1 || !Directory.Exists(args[0]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Arg should be: C:\\ (or your drive letter)");
                return;
            }

            const int RandomFilesToCreate = int.MaxValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < RandomFilesToCreate; i++)
            {
                string FileName = CreateRandomFile(args[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(i + ") Wrote file " + FileName);
            }
        }

        static Random gRan = new Random();
        static string CreateRandomFile(string Path)
        {
            byte[] FileContent = new byte[gRan.Next(2,10) * 1024] ;

            // generate a random filename
            string FileName = Path + "\\TempF_" + gRan.Next(0, int.MaxValue) + "_" + gRan.Next(0, int.MaxValue) + "_" + gRan.Next(0, int.MaxValue) + ".tmp";
            while(File.Exists(FileName))
                FileName = Path + "\\TempF_" + gRan.Next(0, int.MaxValue) + "_" + gRan.Next(0, int.MaxValue) + "_" + gRan.Next(0, int.MaxValue) + ".tmp";

            // fill with random bytes.
            gRan.NextBytes(FileContent);

            // Write to disk
            File.WriteAllBytes(FileName, FileContent);
            return FileName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -7):

I can't really make the two terms "Windows" and "4TB of data" match in my head. Windows is a desktop OS written for the average user who does a bit of Word and browsing with IE. If you have special needs, use a server OS like Linux. It comes with all the tools you need to handle large amounts of data. You also get FS benchmark tools like [bonnie](http://www.textuality.com/bonnie/).

You can also choose from a large set of filesystems where some (like ZFS) are designed for huge sizes (Exabytes). NTFS can theoretically handle this amount of data but I'm not aware that anyone has actually tried this. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) for some pointers.

[EDIT] Since you use a "server" edition of Windows (which translates to "Desktop OS with a couple of nice wizards to set up the network"), you must have a professional support contract with Microsoft. This means you can just call them, explain your problem and let them tell you how to solve it.

Sorry, I'm being unnecessarily sarcastic here but I find all this really amusing ;) Just because the marketing department slaps a "Server" label on something doesn't mean that a professional administrator would buy it. I'd be surprised if someone would post an answer to the effect "we did the same thing and we could get it working reliably and to our satisfaction".

Comment: i was talking about windows 2003 server, 
All i need is a small tool to create files. Please stop talking about performance of windows or which OS is better or IE etc...I've my reasons to say Win2k3 server is the best server...

Comment: If you can't get the right tools, then it's not the right OS for you.

Comment: Hating the solution will help as much as hitting your head against the wall ;)

Comment: @Aaron. 99% of the time the choice of technology is out of your hands, the decision is made for us by others, and we're left carrying the can. You could say that we should leave our BAD technology jobs and go work for GOOD technology employers . . . but unfortunately we live in the real world, and that isn't as easily done as said. -1 from me, for the "Pointing and laughing" content of this answer.

Comment: @Aaron - what an unhelpful answer, -1

Comment: I'm still waiting for anyone to say "We've done it and it worked". :)

Comment: @Binary: Agreed. I just doubt that the guys who pay calvin will be very happy with the results even if he gets past his tests. So either he'll get slapped for delivering what he was told or he'll get slapped for saying "Windows doesn't deliver". When I see questions like this one, I always have this image of an 18-wheeler that someone wants to use to go shopping and then, they start complaining that they can't find a parking lot.